# How do I enable SCIM for primary user store? (wso2carbon)

Tags: wso2, scim

I am working with wso2 carbon and am I trying to work though some of the SCIM examples, however, when I try to add a user to the store I get the following error:

```
{"Errors":[{"code":"500","description":"Cannot add user through scim to user store . SCIM is not enabled for user store PRIMARY"}]}
```

I have searched through the documentation, but I can't seem to find any information on how to enable SCIM for the primary user store.  I know it has to be some setting in an XML somewhere, but I am just unable to find any information on this.

Does anyone know what I need to change/modify to get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it, I must have overlooked it multiple times... in the user-mgt.xml file you need this set to true in the UserStoreManager you are using

```
<Property name-"SCIMEnabled">true</Property>
```